# Game programming difficult mathematical issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, positioning

The question I am about to ask could be somewhat challenging. I will try to make this as clear and cohesive as possible.

I am currently making a game, in which I have a 'laser ring,' as shown here:

[image: A laser ring]

This laser ring, when prompted, will fire a 'grappling hook' which is simply the image shown below. This image's `frame.width` property is adjusted to make it fire (lengthen) and retract (shorten.) It starts at a width of 0, and as the frames progress, it lengthens until reaching the desired point.

[image]

This grappling hook, when fired, should line up with the ring so that they appear to be one item. Refer to the image below for clarity:

[image]

*Note that the grappling hook's width changes almost every frame, so a constant width cannot be assumed.

Something else to note is that, for reasons that are difficult to explain, I can only access the `frame.center` property of the grappling hook and not the `frame.origin` property.

So, my question to you all is this: How can I, accessing only the `frame.center.x` and `frame.center.y` properties of the grappling hook, place it around the laser ring in such a way that it appears to be seamlessly extending from the ring as shown in the above image - presumably calculated based on the angle and width of the grappling hook at any given frame?

Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: I kinda know how to do this but I cant really figure out how to explain to you . Heres a clue : A point on the circumference of a circle making an angle theta with the center is given by coordinates (Radius* cos(theta) , Radius * sin(theta)) .

Comment: You should probably post this on the math stackexchange .

Comment: How are you rotating the grappling hook (changing its angle) if you can only access the center ?

Comment: @Samhan could help, thanks. And I felt it would be better understood by someone who had programming knowledge as well as mathematical knowledge. Also, when I say i can only access the `frame.center` property, I simply meant I could not access `frame.origin`. This doesn't mean I can't access the angle or the width.

Comment: @Fogmeister Great! I look forward to it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've done this exact same thing in my own app.

The trick I did to make it easier was to have a function to calculate the "unitVector" of the line.

i.e. the vector change in the line based on a line length of 1.

It just uses simple pythagorus...

```
- (CGSize)unitVectorFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
{
    //distance between start an end
    float dX = end.x - start.x;
    float dY = end.y - start.y;
    float distance = sqrtf(dX * dX + dY * dY);  // simple pythagorus

    //unit vector is just the difference divided by the distance
    CGSize unitVector = CGSizeMake(dX/distance, dY/distance);

    return unitVector;
}
```

Note... it doesn't matter which way round the start and end are as squaring the numbers will only give positive values.

Now you can use this vector to get to any point along the line between the two points (centre of the circle and target).

So, the start of the line is ...

```
CGPoint center = // center of circle
CGPoint target = // target
float radius = //radius of circle

float dX = center.x - target.x;
float dY = center.y - target.y;

float distance = sqrtf(dX * dX + dY * dY);

CGSize unitVector = [self unitVectorFromPoint:center toPoint:target];

CGPoint startOfLaser = CGPointMake(center.x + unitVector.x * radius, center.y + unitVector.y * radius).

CGPoint midPointOfLaser = CGPointMake(center.x + unitVecotr.x * distance * 0.5, center.y + unitVector.y * distance * 0.5);
```

This just multiplies the unit vector by how far you want to go (radius) to get to the point on the line at that distance.

Hope this helps :D

If you want the mid point between the two points then you just need to change "radius" to be the distance that you want to calculate and it will give you the mid point. (and so on).

Comment: This is a pretty neat way of doing this . I wish i could upvote this once more.

Comment: Thanks :D I had to do this quite a lot in my Sudoku Wiki app and it got to the point where I had calculations all over the place. In the end I wrote a couple of functions to reuse all over the place.

Comment: I was thinking of using trigonometry but that was just too confusing . This is better.

Comment: Yes, I started using trig also :D and yes it got REALLY confusing.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. You just made my job alot easier. Thank you very much for this, it's something I have been stuck on for a great deal of time now. :)